# Are there already python generators that do these basic things?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I found myself using these 2 custom generators and thinking "there's got to be an itertools function or something that already does this!  Didn't find any though.  Am I missing something?  Thanks!

```
def gothru(iters):
  for i in iters:
    for j in i:
      yield j

def overnover(fn,startval):
  val = startval
  while True:
    val = fn(val)
    yield val
```

EDIT: i was later imagining how `overnover` could be used to generate the fibonacci sequence, and i realized that it would need to be generalized to allow the function to have more than one argument

```
def overnover(fn,*args):
  while True:
    args = fn(*args)
    return args
```

then you could do:

```
fibInfo = overnover(lambda x,y: (x+y, x), 1, 1)
```

-> (2,1) ... (3, 2) ... (5, 3) ... (8, 5) ...
and then:

```
fib = imap(lambda x:x[0], fibInfo)
```

-> 2 ... 3 ... 5 ... 8 ...

thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is [`chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

The closest thing to `overnover` is something like [`tabulate`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def tabulate(function, start=0):
    "Return function(0), function(1), ..."
    return imap(function, count(start))
```

which is a special case of your function where it outputs sequential numbers. `count` also takes a `step`, so you could generalize this to

```
def tabulate(function, start=0, step=1):
    "Return function(0), function(0+step), ..."
    return imap(function, count(start, step))
```

Here is a version of `overnover` that would let you send values into the sequence:

```
def overnover(fn, val):
    while True:
        val = fn(val)
        val = (yield val) or val
```

Comment: hellyeah!  I knew about chain but didn't know about from_iterable.  thanks agf

Comment: I just play around with mathematical sequences a lot.  In mathematics (as you may know already), the term for applying the same function over and over to a value is, confusingly enough, "iterating".  Nice to have a terse, general, lazy-evaluation way to do these iterative sequences.

Comment: now I'm curious -- why would `overnover` seem good for monitoring?

Comment: I added the closest thing to `overnover` but it's a very special case of your generator.

Comment: Well, if you had a iterative function, and you don't know how many steps it will take to get to where you need it to be, seeing the intermediate values to know when to stop is what I meant by monitoring. Also, if the function actually operated by side effects, this would be a way for it to report progress through a side-channel.

Comment: You can also use `send` to send info into the generator, so it could be expanded to by default use it's last yield as input, but also be able to take a new value, if for some reason it needs to adjust or skip a value.

Comment: true that.  i was just now imagining how `overnover` could be used to perform the fibonacci sequence, and i realized that it would need to be generalized to allow the function to have more than one argument

Comment: @agf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2642/discussion-between-murftown-and-agf)